Problem with Oracle Database 21 Express Edition Installation: Listener Configuration Error
I'm encountering an issue while installing Oracle Database 21 Express Edition (XE) on Windows. During the installation process, I get the following error:
{IDS_OracleConfigDIg_NetworkConfigFaildMsg} An error occurred while configuring Oracle XE listener.
The error specifically occurs during the "Configuring Oracle XE Listener" step.
Here’s a screenshot of the error for reference:

I've tried restarting the installation and verifying my system configuration, but the issue persists. Has anyone encountered this problem before or knows how to resolve it?

This is off-topic for this site. But have you looked at the logs, as the message says, to see what the actual problem is?
